# why the android gradle version and gradle version is different

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Recently I ran into a problem and solved it by degrading the android gradle version according to [Update Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

But, I did't get why these two gradle versions are different ? can anyone explain this